# have an error while i tape Php bin/console make:entity

Tags: symfony

Php bin/console make:entity

Class name of the entity to create or update (e.g. AgreeableElephant):
 >

Aborted.

make:entity [-a|--api-resource] [--regenerate] [--overwrite] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--]  []

Answer (score 0):

There is a console issue in php 7.4 what version are you using ? you need to update to 7.4.1 https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/34702

Comment: i'm using 7.4.0

Comment: I thinks it's easy to upgrade with wamp sorry i'm not using or but i hope my answer was clear

Comment: Can you please accept my answer if you find it useful